git submodule update fails for private submodules
I'm trying to get a private repo which references numerous private submodules working. I'm using ssh and cannot use https to clone them due to GitHub's new restriction. I have access to all private submodules and have added my public keys to GitHub. I can clone the repo, can initialize and sync the submodules but when I try
Cloning into git submodule update --recursive , I get fatal: clone of 'git@github.com:user/repo.git' into submodule path 'path/to/main/module' failed ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com<user>: Name or service not known fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Is there a solution or workaround for this?
All repo entries in both .git/config and .gitmodules are ssh links
Any help would be much appreciated!
I tried:
generating a pass-less ssh key
running the command with sudo -- get the same error but with "(public key)" added to the end. The public key on my computer matches the one on GitHub.
